# Do i need https for a facebook login?

Tags: facebook, https

```
This must be derived from Canvas URL, Secure Canvas URL, Site URL, Mobile Site URL, Page Tab URL or Secure Page Tab URL. Check and correct the following domains: www.mydomain.net
```

Does anyone know what this means? Do i need https for a facebook login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need for https. it works as well with with http